# Vercel doesn't recognize dynamic routes in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, vercel

**Summary**

My REST API: `/pages/api/users/[...catchall].js` is not converted to dynamic routes in production (Vercel).

**Issue**

When doing a GET towards `https://my-domain.com/api/users/me` I expect to get some data and a 200 status, but I receive a 404. However, if I do a GET towards `https://my-domain.com/api/users/[...catchall]` it works and I get the data I want. Locally and at Netlify the API routes will be converted to dynamic routes, but Vercel does not.

How do I tell Vercel that API routes with brackets are dynamic and not the actual name of the route?

"next": "^13.2.4",

node 18.x

I tried to upgrade nextjs to 14, but the result is the same.